# Remove Duplicates From A Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing problem with removing duplicate from a single row. I want to loop through all rows in a range and remove duplicate from a single row without effecting rest of data in sheet. Here is sample data:

```
+---------------+------+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| name          | num1 | num2 | mun3 | emial1        | email2        |
+---------------+------+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| ali zubair    | 1    | 2    | 1    | az@az.com     | az@az.com     |
+---------------+------+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| tosif         | 1    | 2    | 2    | t@zb.com      | t@gb.com      |
+---------------+------+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| qadeer satter | 3    | 2    | 3    | qs@mtm.com    | star@mtn.com  |
+---------------+------+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| asif          | 4    | 3    | 2    |               |               |
+---------------+------+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| hamid         | 1    | 5    | 2    | hamid@beta.ds | hamid@beta.ds |
+---------------+------+------+------+---------------+---------------+
```

Below code removes duplicate rows based on column 2, it is not applicable in my case.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:f100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2), Header:=xlYes
```

I have no idea how I can remove duplicate from a selected row range. So far I have the code that will loop through all rows in my data.

```
    Sub removeRowDubs()
      Dim nextRang As Range
      Dim sCellStr As String, eCellStr As String
      Dim dRow As Long
       
      dRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For dRow = 2 To dRow
               sCellStr = Range("A" & dRow).Offset(0, 1).Address
               eCellStr = Cells(dRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
               
        Set nextRang = Range(sCellStr, eCellStr)
             Debug.Print nextRang.Address
             
        Next
           
End Sub
```

So what I need is some code to do what I need inserted after below code.

```
Set nextRang = Range(sCellStr, eCellStr)
```

**If there is a simple solution to this like ".RemoveDuplicates" then please let me know.** As of now I am thinking of doing this through looping but it seems complex as I think I will need at least 3 "for each" loops and 3 "if conditions", 2 more row ranges and probably something else when I start doing it like that.

I hope I made my question clear and I will really appreciate your help. I am new at Excel VBA coding, your patience is needed..

So I also worked on the code to remove duplicates for rows. Below is my code, its working for me. It is complex and people over stackoverflow provided better code.

```
    Sub removeRowDublicates()
      Dim nextRang As Range                             ' Variables for
      Dim sCellStr As String, eCellStr As String        ' Going through all rows
      Dim dRow As Long                                  ' And selecting row range
        
        dRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    ' This code selects the                                         
        For dRow = 2 To dRow                         ' next row in the data                                                           
               sCellStr = Range("A" & dRow).Offset(0, 1).Address                            
               eCellStr = Cells(dRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address        
        Set nextRang = Range(sCellStr, eCellStr)                                                       
                                                             
         
        Dim aRange As Range, aCell As Range                ' Variables for                               
        Dim dubCheckCell As Range, dubCheckRange As Range  ' Loops to remove
        Dim dubCheckCell1 As Range                         ' Dublicates from                             
        Dim columnNum As Integer                           ' Current row                                
        
           
        Set aRange = nextRang
        columnNum = Range("b2:f2").Columns.Count + 1
        aRange.Select
        
              For Each aCell In aRange    'Loop for selecting 1 cell, if not blank from range to check its value against all other cell values
                      

                                 If aCell.Value <> "" Then
                                    Set dubCheckCell = aCell
                                 Else
                                             GoTo nextaCell   'If current cell is blank then go to next cell in range
                                 End If
                                 
                      If dubCheckCell.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "" Then                   'Selects range by offsetting 1 cell to right from current cell being checked for dublicate value
                   Set dubCheckRange = Range(dubCheckCell.Offset(, 1), dubCheckCell.Offset(, 1).End(xlToRight))
                   Else
                   Set dubCheckRange = Range(dubCheckCell.Offset(0, 1).Address)
                   End If
                                                
                                 
    For Each dubCheckCell1 In dubCheckRange   'Loop that goes through all cells in range selected by above if-statement
      Do While dubCheckCell1.Column <= columnNum
         If dubCheckCell = dubCheckCell1 Then
                 dubCheckCell1.ClearContents
                         Else
                          End If
             GoTo nextdubCheckCell1
             Loop         'For do while
nextdubCheckCell1:
        Next dubCheckCell1            'Next for dubCheckRange
nextaCell:
        Next aCell                    'Next for aRange
              
              Next    'For drow
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: On which column(s) will the search be based? A-D, B-E or all Columns e.g. A-AB? Do you have data to the left or to the right of the columns that has to stay in place?

Comment: As you can see from data, duplicates are all over row so it can't be based on one column. E.g. see Row2 - Num1 and Num3 are duplicates so are the email1 and email 2.  What I am thinking is selecting 1 cell from row then check it against all other cells in the same row, if cell value is equal to any other cell in row then remove that cell value. Select 2nd cell from row if not empty and repeat

Comment: E.g. in Row2 , Name ali zubair select cell1 that has "1" as value and check it with all remaining cells num2, num3, email1 and email2. So in 1st go 1 is removed from Num3 column. But it will be complex, I can attemp doing this but was wondering if there is any simple solution. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testRemoveRowDuplicates()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long, i As Long
  
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  For i = 2 To lastRow
     Set rng = sh.Range("C" & i & ":D" & i)
     rng.Replace rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value, "", xlWhole
     Set rng = sh.Range("D" & i)
     rng.Replace rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value, "", xlWhole
     Set rng = sh.Range("F" & i)
     rng.Replace rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value, "", xlWhole
  Next i
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that a name cannot be duplicate in the email columns. It removes duplicates on each category (names and emails).

If you really need to check each value of the row, please, use the next variant:

```
Sub testRemoveRowDuplicatesBis()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 3 To 6 'last column
       Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Cells(i, j), sh.Cells(i, 6))
       rng.Replace rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value, "", xlWhole
     Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ali Zubair: Did you find time to check the above code? Does it do what you need?

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru your code is working. its nice and compact. I did worked on my own code and got it to remove duplicates but it is complex and large. Thanks for the help. Really Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can use some VBA nested loops to do this - loop the rows, and then have two column loops to check the values of the cells:

```
Sub sRemoveRowDubs()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLastCol As Long
    Dim lngRow1 As Long
    Dim lngCol1 As Long
    Dim lngCol2 As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lngLastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For lngRow1 = 1 To lngLastRow
        For lngCol1 = 1 To lngLastCol
            For lngCol2 = lngCol1 + 1 To lngLastCol
                If ws.Cells(lngRow1, lngCol1) = ws.Cells(lngRow1, lngCol2) Then
                    ws.Cells(lngRow1, lngCol2) = ""
                End If
            Next lngCol2
        Next lngCol1
    Next lngRow1
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sRemoveRowDubs", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Hello @Applecore , your code is also working. I will study it as well. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use formula and create a new table.

Array (CSE) Formula for Num1 column, enter the formula in formula bar, press control+Shift+Enter and then select the cell copy to Num2 and Num3. Then select all three cells and copy down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$D2,1,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H2:H2,$B2:$D2),0)),"")
```

Array (CSE) Formula for email1 column, enter the formula in formula bar, press control+Shift+Enter and then select the cell copy to email2. Then select those two cells and copy down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E2:$F2,1,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($K2:K2,$E2:$F2),0)),"")
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe something like this?

```
Sub test()
Set rngName = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In rngName
For i = 1 To 4
Set Rng = Range(cell.Offset(0, i + 1), Cells(cell.Row, 6))
Set c = Rng.Find(cell.Offset(0, i).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not c Is Nothing Then c.ClearContents
Next i
Next cell
End Sub
```

> What I am thinking is selecting 1 cell from row then check it against
> all other cells in the **same row**

The code assumes that there will be no blank in between row with value under column NAME (column A), and all the name value is unique. This is for the first loop.

The second loop is the how many cell in the same row to check, in this case there are 4 cells to check (num1, num2, num3 and email1) then so does the checking are 4 times ---> in the same row : check num1 against num2, num3, email1 and email2 ... check num2 against num3, email1 and email2 .... check num3 against email1 and email2... then finally check email1 against email2. On each check, if the same value is found, then the code put blank to the found cell.

Answer (score 0):

### Clear Duplicate Entries By Row

- Copy the complete code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Only run the first `Sub`, the other two are being called.
- Adjust the **const**ants in the first `Sub`, including the **workbook**.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub clearDups()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRowAddress As String = "A2:F2"
    Const LastRowColumn As Long = 1
    Const Replacement As Variant = Empty
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Data First Row Range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(FirstRowAddress)
    ' Define Data Range and write its values to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: getRangeValuesFR Data, rng, LastRowColumn
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Sub
    ' In data array, clear duplicate values by row
    ' (from the top and from the left).
    replaceDupsByRow Data, Replacement
    ' Write modified values from Data Array to Data Range.
    rng.Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Data
    
End Sub

Sub getRangeValuesFR(ByRef Data As Variant, _
                     ByRef FirstRowRange As Range, _
                     Optional ByVal LastRowColumn As Long = 1)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    If LastRowColumn = 0 Then GoSub LastRow0 Else GoSub LastRowN
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRowRange.Row Then Exit Sub
    
    Set rng = FirstRowRange.Resize(rng.Row - FirstRowRange.Row + 1)
    If rng.Row > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

LastRow0:
    With FirstRowRange
        Set rng = .Worksheet.Columns(.Column).Resize(, .Columns.Count) _
                  .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    End With
    Return

LastRowN:
    With FirstRowRange
        Debug.Print .Columns(LastRowColumn).Address
        Set rng = .Worksheet.Columns(.Columns(LastRowColumn).Column) _
                  .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    End With
    Return

End Sub

Sub replaceDupsByRow(ByRef Data As Variant, _
                     Optional ByVal Replacement As Variant = Empty)
    
    Dim Curr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, l As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2) - 1
            Curr = Data(i, j + 1)
            If Curr <> Replacement Then GoSub loopSubRows
        Next j
    Next i
    Exit Sub

loopSubRows:
    For l = 1 To j
        If Curr = Data(i, l) Then
            Data(i, j + 1) = Replacement: Exit For
        End If
    Next l
    Return

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, thanks for replying to my problem. Your code is also working. I appreciate it.